# How to make text interpolation work inside css functions and router links

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, code-reuse, vue-props

I was trying to implement a reusable card component, so I printed them out inside variable properties that is changed image by image

This is my code. As for title, it works perfectly. I implemented it many times, so my issue is different. I also added this props' text inside mustaches, so I can change link and image out of my card, but it doesn't work, so I need your help. I might just not understand how text interpolation works. But I think that vue supports the way to create reusable cards within a component

```
<template>
      <RouterLink class="card" to="{{ link }}">
      <div class="card__background" style="background-image: url({{ image }})"></div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <h3 class="card__heading">{{ title }}</h3>
      </div>
      </RouterLink>
      

</template>
<script>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router';
export default {
    props: ['link', 'image', 'title'],
    created() {
      console.log(this.link)
      console.log(this.image)
      console.log(this.title)
    },
    
    
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the v-bind directive. This directive allows you to bind the value of an HTML attribute to a dynamic expression.

Here's how you can modify your code to use the v-bind directive:

```
  <template>
     <RouterLink class="card" v-bind:to="link">
     <div class="card__background" v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` 
     }"></div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <h3 class="card__heading">{{ title }}</h3>
    </div>
   </RouterLink>

 </template>

 <script>
    import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router';
    export default {
    props: ['link', 'image', 'title'],
    created() {
    console.log(this.link)
    console.log(this.image)
    console.log(this.title)
    }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: I gotta try it out. If it works, I'm grateful to you. Reusable components save me from repeating the same code over and over

Comment: That works, thx. Before I accept you answer, do you tell me more about this chunk of code   ``v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }"``. I want to figure out how it works, so I will never get bothered by the same problem. I Why do we use dollar prefix here?

Comment: The v-bind directive is used to bind the value of an expression to an element's attribute. In this case, the expression is { backgroundImage: url(${image}) }, which is an object containing a single key-value pair. The key is backgroundImage and the value is a string that includes the image prop, interpolated using template literals (the backticks).

Comment: The $ prefix is used to denote a variable in JavaScript. In this case, the ${image} part of the string is a template literal placeholder, which means that it will be replaced with the value of the image variable when the string is evaluated.

So, when the v-bind directive is applied to the style attribute of the element, the resulting attribute will be style="backgroundImage: url(<value of image prop>)". The value of the image prop will be inserted into the string in place of the ${image} placeholder, and the resulting string will be used as the value of the style attribute.